# Error handling in toBlocking()

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm refactoring an app to reactive paradigm using RxJava. I'm doing it step by step so I need to use `toBlocking()` in some cases in order to respect the interfaces, for the moment. How can I handle an error when use `toBlocking()`?

Before, I had something like this:

```
public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    try {
        return repository.getEmployees();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new MyCustomException();
    } 
}
```

Now, the repository has a reactive interface (returns `Observable<List<Employee>>`), so I'm doing this:

```
public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return repository.getEmployees().toBlocking().single(); 
}
```

Subscription to `repository.getEmployees()` may return an error `Observable`. My question is: how can I handle this error keeping it blocking?

I have found out a method `singleOrDefault()`, but something like `singleOrThrow(new MyCustomException())` would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that, you will need to wrap it with try/catch block,
`toBlocking()` transform the `Observable` to `BlockingObservable` which is not exactly reactive block, more like fancy collection, it's now lack the power of composing Observables, operators, controlling the thread/parallelism, and the basic construct of async API, which has error handling built in, (`onError()`)

That what the docs stated about `BlockingObservable`:

> It can be useful for testing and demo purposes, but is generally
>   inappropriate for production applications (if you think you need to
>   use a BlockingObservable this is usually a sign that you should
>   rethink your design).

So, what is the point to act with blocking observable? if you can't change the interface to `Observable`, then you probably missing all the point of using Rx and `Observable`, which is (at ideal) to abstract out every event based operation in the system, and then being able to use the power of Operators/Composition/Async management and construct event streams in your system.
If you just wrap some API operation with Observable and then return it back to non-reactive world, then the consumer of the API can't enjoy all the aforementioned benefits of Rx.
So, I think you should reconsider what is the purpose of doing that, and what is your final goal, you can consider replacing to Reactive approach in few places in your system for start.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Of course, you are right. It's useless use a reactive paradigm and then return to non-reactive model. But as I say in the question, I'm refactoring step by step: in the future I won't use BlockingObservable, but a complete reactive model. You clarified my doubt: I need to use a try/catch block. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We have another option to handler error by using variant method to handle error as **onErrorReturn** ...

```
public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return repository.getEmployees().onErrorReturn{
       //Do something 
       //Then return value in case error happened
    }.toBlocking().single(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your MyCustomException is wrapped in RuntimeException by Rx, so you should catch RuntimeException then call getCuase() to get MyCustomException like below.

```
public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    try {
        return repository.getEmployees().toBlocking().single(); 
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        MyCustomException myCustomException = e.getCause();
        if (e != null) {
            // caught MyCustomException
        }
    }
}
```